# Do a function that transform a string in int from a base

Tags: c

I need to do a function that will transform a string in a number base decimal, from a base that it giving to us.

> Ex : someone give me a string in base hexa and I need to make it decimal

I should multiplied the position of the characters  in the base by the power multiplied by the length of the base ?

Something like this

```
Indexbase * ( lenghtbase^power)
```

And I addition everything to have my number finish ?

Comment: Why not use a combination of [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) ?

Comment: I cannot use any function have to create my own :(

Comment: What is the highest possible base? Because if it can be higher than 36 you have to tell us what the next character after 'Z' is.

Comment: I don't have precision on the bigger base but we can assume that it should not go over 36

Answer (score 0):

You follow this code:

```
int hexadecimalToDecimal(char hexVal[]) 
{    
    int len = strlen(hexVal); 

    // Initializing base value to 1, i.e 16^0 
    int base = 1; 

    int dec_val = 0; 

    // Extracting characters as digits from last character 
    for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--) 
    {    
        // if character lies in '0'-'9', converting  
        // it to integral 0-9 by subtracting 48 from 
        // ASCII value. 
        if (hexVal[i]>='0' && hexVal[i]<='9') 
        { 
            dec_val += (hexVal[i] - 48)*base; 

            // incrementing base by power 
            base = base * 16; 
        } 

        // if character lies in 'A'-'F' , converting  
        // it to integral 10 - 15 by subtracting 55  
        // from ASCII value 
        else if (hexVal[i]>='A' && hexVal[i]<='F') 
        { 
            dec_val += (hexVal[i] - 55)*base; 

            // incrementing base by power 
            base = base*16; 
        } 
    } 

    return dec_val; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks you , so you multiplied by 16 ( the length of the base )  Everytime you have a new number to convert  :0 , it work as a power

Comment: Yeah but the multiplied power work , I just have to adapt it by county the length of my base

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty implementation, which doesn't cover all corner cases but should work for bases from 2 to 16. I felt that would be easier than trying to describe the method to you. Please don't copy-paste and use directly, try to understand the logic and rewrite the way it suits you. Also, please note that the result is correct, but printed in **reverse** - I leave it as an exercise to the reader to fix that!

```
#include <stdio.h>

char symbols[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

int string_to_num(char *num, int base)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(*num)
    {
        int i;
        result *= base;     
        for(i = 0; i < base; i++)
        {
            if(*num == symbols[i])
            {
                result += i;
                break;
            }
        }
        *num++;
    }
    return result;
}

void num_to_string(int num, int base, char *str)
{
    int result = 0;
    do
    {
        *str = symbols[num % base];
        num /= base;
        str++;
    }while(num);
    *str = 0;
}

void convert_num(char *num, int from_base, int to_base, char *out)
{
    num_to_string(string_to_num(num, from_base), to_base, out);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf[10];
    char result[20] = {0};
    int from_base, to_base;
    scanf("%s", buf);
    scanf("%d", &from_base);
    scanf("%d", &to_base);  
    convert_num(buf, from_base, to_base, result);
    printf("\r\nResult in base %d is %s\r\n", to_base, result);
    return 0;
}
```

Cheers!